# Simple and nice way to increment nullable Int in Kotlin

Tags: syntax, kotlin

What is the simplest and best readable way to increment nullable Int in Kotlin? Is there any other way than doing this?

```
var myInt: Int? = 3
myInt = if(myInt!=null) myInt+1 else null
```

This is quite fine if myInt is simple variable, but it can grow very long when myInt is some longer expression.

Comment: https://youtu.be/hp3Rceh6rnE?t=336

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can call the operator in its invocable way as:

```
myInt = myInt?.inc()
```

Note that the `inc()` operator **does not** mutate the value of its receiver but creates a new value. This implies the following statement does not change `myInt`:

```
val myInt: Int? = null
myInt?.inc() // myInt still being null
```

Neither :

```
val myInt: Int? = 5
myInt?.inc() // myInt still being 5
```

Comment: You can also use `myInt?.plus(i)` if you want to increment by an arbitrary amount.

Comment: `public val maxFailCount: Integer? = null  maxFailCount?.toInt()` Is it ok?

Comment: @DevendraSingh yes, the lines run without error. But try not to use `Integer` class in kotlin. Use `Int` instead. IntelliJ also warns you about this.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers present shorter alternatives, I'll present how to properly use the basic if-construct:

```
var myInt: Int? = 3
if (myInt != null) myInt++
```

It's much like in Java, you don't have to add any new layer of complication.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inc`. In Kotlin, all the operators are converted into method call. See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) for more details.

```
var myInt: Int? = 3
myInt = myInt?.inc()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInt: Int? = 3
myInt = myInt?.inc()
```

Note that I've assigned the value returned by `inc()` to `myInt`, as [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) states the following:

> The inc() and dec() functions must return a value, which will be assigned to the variable on which the ++ or -- operation was used. They shouldn't mutate the object on which the inc or dec was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is [crgarridos'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48223839/2735286) one.

Here is an alternative in case you want to increment by other values:

```
var myInt: Int? = 1
val n = myInt?.plus(1)
println(n)
```

This prints:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to use also/apply? Is it looks bigger OR it's not a best practice to do so?

```
myInt?.dec().also { myInt= it }
```

VS

```
myInt = myInt?.dec()
```

Comment: I think the version with `.also` is a little overcomplicated and less readable.